# Computing quantities for repeated uses in a plot

Tags: tikz-pgf

In the following MWE

```
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}

\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}
    \addplot [domain=-1:1]
    {(x*cos(x) / exp(x)) * (cos(x*cos(x) / exp(x)) + tan(x*cos(x) / exp(x)))};
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I am computing the quantity `cos(x)*x / exp(x)` three times to plot the function. Is there a way to compute it once and use it three times? I know I can declare a function using

```
\tikzset{
  declare function={
    foo(\x)=cos(\x)*\x / exp(\x);},
}
```

then use `foo(x)*(cos(foo(x)) + tan(foo(x)) )`. But that would still be computing the function 3 times, right? My real example is much more complicated so I want to avoid repeated evaluation.

Comment: Math says to check if the function is continuous, then check the limits (to use as domain) and plot the `x*cos(x)+tan(x)` instead... This would save much time from the computer (that seems to be your problem).. and will add (possibly) more time and effort to your work. [We can't have everything :P ]

Comment: First question: are you sure that you want to compute this function? In `cos(x)`, `x` is interpreted as degrees. Second, if you call `x*cos(x)/exp(x) =:X`, then your function is `f(X)=X * cos (X)+tan(X)`. Now you can use a parametric plot to avoid double computation, i.e. `plot ({invX(x),f(x)})` in an appropriate range. Unfortunately, in your case inverting `X` seems to be nontrivial.

Comment: I really just came up with a complicated looking function because I didn't want to bore people with the details of my real function. The question still stands: How do I assign these computations to a temporary variable then use the variable multiple times.

Comment: Well, if you had a simpler function, my above trick would work easily. If the function is as complicated as above, you could try to invert it with a computer algebra system.